# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Pending '

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, valueerror

I am trying to update existing `xlsm` file depending on `dataframe` values `rows` by informing the columns I want to update in the excl file by using this code of `pandas` df

```
frm_mwfy_to_te_col = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Governance_Tracker - Copy - Copy.xlsm',
                                   usecols=['Pending  ', 'Pending Status'], header=1, axis=1)
```

and this is the part of my code which I have error there

```
for index, row in filtered_data_cond1['SiteCode'].items():
    for col, _ in frm_mwfy_to_te_col.items(): ws.cell(row=index + 3,
                                                      column=int(col)).value = 'Value1', 'Value2'
```

as the `filtered_data_cond1['SiteCode']` is the rows I want to update

```
filtered_data_cond1 = all_data.loc[all_data['SiteCode'].str.contains('|'.join(frm_mwfy_to_te.Subject))]
```

and this is my `all_data`

```
all_data = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Governance_Tracker - Copy - Copy.xlsm'
                         , header=1).drop(['#'], axis=1)
```

and I found this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/PycharmProjects/MyALLRefProf/MyExp.py", line 54, in <module>
    column=int(col).isnull()).value = 'Value1', 'Value2'  # example
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Pending
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that the columns in your `frm_mwfy_to_te_col` dataframe are (from what I can gather) called `'Pending  '` and `'Pending Status'`. When you try `int(col)` in that line of code, you are attempting to cast the string `'Pending  '` to an `int`, which can't be done.

Possibly try renaming the columns as integers. Or, even better, rework your logic to allow for the column names to be strings in a more pythonic way.

**Edit:**

Try changing your problem section of code to:

```
for index, row in filtered_data_cond1['SiteCode'].items():
    for col_num in range(len(frm_mwfy_to_te_col.columns)): 
        ws.cell(row=index + 3, column=col_num + 1).value = 'Value1', 'Value2'
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your support, So I do not need to rename columns I, so how can I use logic for the column names to be strings??

Comment: I did the same way for the rows and works fine, but it doesn't for for `headers`

Comment: @DevyToly See if the latest edit helps. I'm not sure if you need the name of the column for `we.cell()`, or the position of the column.

Comment: I just need the `position` of the columns, as I tried this edited code and found this error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` for the needed rows works fine and get the position, but for columns doesn't work

Comment: @DevyToly Ok I get you now. Try the latest edit. You may need to add an offset to `col_num`, similar to what you did for row with the `+3`, to make it match up with the excel sheet.

Comment: huh finally I found another error for edited code `ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1` :)

Comment: @DevyToly Try adding 1 to `col_num`.

Comment: I tried and works fine thanks a lot but works for one value only when try to do this `ws.cell(row=index + 3, column=col_num + 3).value = 'Value1'`
but when I try this `ws.cell(row=index + 3, column=col_num + 3).value = 'Value1', 'Value2'` it gives me this errror `ValueError: Cannot convert ('Value1', 'Value2') to Excel` `raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))`, How ever I'll accept your answer, It's solved a bit

Comment: In other way I want to put `Value2` in `Pending ` column and `Value2` in `Pending Status`

Comment: I imagine that there's something like this `ws.cell(row=index + 3, column=col_num + 1).value = frm_mwfy_to_te_col.loc[frm_mwfy_to_te_col['Pending ']['Value1']] ,frm_mwfy_to_te_col.loc[frm_mwfy_to_te_col['Pending Status'] ['Value2']]`